# I've kept charged from EIP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip, eip

I've made a few EIPs in Tokyo region before and I released all of them already and there is no EIP anymore.

the way i released them is not the right way in the official doc.
i just terminated instances that were using the EIPs and then released them later.

But I've noticed that I've been charged from EIP and the billing cost is getting up little by little since time past.

Do you think the way i released EIP was wrong so i get keep charged??

I really need to get help to prevent from getting charged I don't need to pay.

please let me know what i should do.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you still using any AWS Service? If not, close the account from Billing Dashboard. Assuming you've released all resources and still getting billed. It happened to me with beanstalk. One month after terminating suddenly I started getting bills. If you think they're illegitimate, contact customer care; they can revert it.

Comment: yes im still using and it's free tier service. if it's free tier, can I just ignore all cost in Billing dashboard?? or is this EIP charging going to be a trouble? and thanks for you reply:)

Comment: I don't remember clearly. I think if it is showing an amount, you'll be billed next month. AWS do not show bills for free tier usage. That's what I remember. Better to get in touch with customer service.

Comment: ok thank you for the advice!

Comment: Do you still remember the commands you issued to release the EIPs? It might have been not properly released and that it incur charges since AWS will charge you for un-assigned EIPs [docs here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/) .

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem , as you know the recommended way to release EIP from documentation.

Now coming to part where you were billed even after terminating instance it is due to EIP not being used and still being locked to your account.

**As yo know there is shortage of IPV4 thus keeping Static IP in your account and not using them caused you to be billed.**

You can contact AWS Billing Support and let them know you were unaware of the charges and I am sure they would be happy to waive it off for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there's really no EIP - in every region
2. Go to CostExplorer and dig down to exact data: what are you billed for? There are a lot of filters to separate things